# Questions about writing formal letters and writing specific dates

Tags: formal-language, ielts

i don't know if these kinds of questions are appropriate to ask in this particular forum but i will take my chances.

I was writing a formal letter for an IELTS task, and I was wondering whether this usage of dates is correct.

"I stayed from Friday the 16th to Sunday 18th in room 215 of the Lilo hotel".

Is it OK to write dates this way?

I was trying to switch the order and see which one sounded more natural and this was the result, but since I am not a native I am not 100% sure.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't know what an IELTS task is. Your quotation sounds perfectly fine to me as a matter of style, but of course in some contexts (like litigation) you might be expected to state the date fully (Friday, June 16th, 2017).

Comment: It's an exam that's worldwide accepted to assess your English level. It's similar to TOEFL. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it is fine, but it seems informal.  If you were talking to a friend, that's perfectly normal and acceptable.  In formal communication, you would want to say, "Friday, April 16th," or simply "April 16th."

"The 16th of April" is technically correct, but that usage is older and sounds a bit unnecessary.  I would keep what you have there.